# Apple TouchID on Ubuntu

Tags: macbook-pro, apple

Is there a way to make TouchID work on MacBook Pro with newest Ubuntu?
I just got the hardware replaced (because of keyboard and not working touchid) and would love to use it.

Cheers

Comment: TouchID is not a feature that Ubuntu supports.  It's a Mac proprietary thing.  There may be a fingerprint scanner type integration, but whether it works properly with the Touch ID hardware on a Macbook is anyone's guess, and I haven't ever seen it requested yet

Comment: ehhh thanks I was hoping someone hacked it already ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way could try is the `fingerprint-gui` package. Here is some instructions of how to install/config: https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2013/03/how-to-get-your-fingerprint-reader-working-in-ubuntu

### Installing Fingerprint GUI

Add the following PPA and install a few packages:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:fingerprint/fingerprint-gui && sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libbsapi policykit-1-fingerprint-gui fingerprint-gui
```

Run the GUI and enroll a few fingers, then restart the session by logging out and back in.

More info regarding this can be found on the Launchpad project page (such as a list of supported hardware, etc.)

[image]

It ought to be noted that the related PolicyKit package for the fingerprint stack will remove the default one (“policykit-gnome” , etc. depending on your environment) thus if you do decide to remove the fingerprint PPA, you must reinstall this package manually, or risk a broken system.

Comment: Does this work with the fingerprint sensor built into MacBooks though?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately no, the fingerprint sensor on modern T2 Macbook laptops (which Apple TouchID uses) has no Linux driver available. It won't be visible to `fingerprint-gui`.

It is unlikely to work any time soon, due to how the T2 security chip and the fingerprint reader [interact](https://www.apple.com/jp/mac/docs/Apple_T2_Security_Chip_Overview.pdf). Unlike normal fingerprint readers (that `fingerprint-gui` can [supports](https://fprint.freedesktop.org/supported-devices.html)), the fingerprint reader itself isn't available to the underlying OS, only to the T2 security chip and the [Secure Enclave](https://support.apple.com/guide/security/secure-enclave-sec59b0b31ff/web).